# A SwiftUI View with one initializer for iOS and macOS

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui

I have the following `SwiftUI` view in my project that supports `macOS 13+` and `iOS 16+`:

```
struct MyTextField: View {
    
    var placeholder: LocalizedStringKey
    #if os (iOS)
    var keyboardType: UIKeyboardType = .default
    #endif
}
```

at call site I can't use a single initializer like this for both operating systems:

```
MyTextField(placeholder: "some placeholder",
                                   keyboardType: .asciiCapableNumberPad,
                                   hasToolbar: true)
```

as it gives a syntax error for `macOS` as it cannot find the `keyboardType` argument in the init signature, I know that I can check for the os at call site using `#if os(iOS)` and provide different init for the target os, but it's  cumbersome when I have a huge form of text fields where I should determine the keyboard type for every text field, is there a way to call one init at call site to support the 2 operating systems in this case ?

Comment: Make an enum that is available on both

Comment: To access the initializer `MyTextField(placeholder:keybaordType:)` from macOS you'll need to remove the`#if os(iOS) #endif` to make the field `keyboardType` available for macOS..

Comment: Did you try to have the same kind of #if that call either initialiser for iOS or for MacOS ?

Comment: @PierreJanineh `UIKeyboardType` is not available on macOS, so it won't work

Comment: @PtitXav yes I can call both initializers using `#if ... #elseif ... #endIf` at call site, but as i mentioned if I have a form that has many `TextFields` then the call site will be cluttered with lots of `#if` checks which is so ugly.

Answer (score 1):

Create your custom enum class with the `UIKeyboardType`s.

```swift
enum MyKeyboardType {
    case `default`,
         asciiCapableNumberPad,
         // ...

#if os(iOS)
    // Consider changing this method to be more generic and scalable
    func getUIType() -> UIKeyboardType {
        switch self {
        case .default:
            return .default
        case .asciiCapableNumberPad:
            return .asciiCapableNumberPad
        // ...
        }
    }
#endif
}
```

And use it in your initializer:

```swift
struct MyTextField: View {
    
    var placeholder: LocalizedStringKey
    var keyboardType: MyKeyboardType?
    
    init(placeholder: LocalizedStringKey,
         keyboardType: MyKeyboardType = .default) {
        
        self.placeholder = placeholder
#if os(iOS)
        self.keyboardType = keyboardType
#endif
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `MyTextField` wraps a normal SwiftUI `TextField`, then you don’t need to pass `keyboardType` as a parameter. You can use the existing `keyboardType` modifier, like this:

```
MyTextField(placeholder: “whatever”)
    #if os(iOS)
    .keyboardType(.asciiCapableNumberPad)
    #endif
```

The `keyboardType` modifier applies to all descendants of the `MyTextField`.

Comment: good suggestion, and yess `MyTextField` wraps a normal SwiftUI `TextField`, but the reason i'm including the keyboardType as a parameter in the `MyTextField` struct is to organize all `TextField` related modifiers in one place which is inside the struct and avoid (where possible) checks for OS outside the struct, so at call site I'm struggling to do something like: `MyTextField(...)`